# Getting ref parameter from COM with InvokeMember call

Tags: c#, com, marshalling, com-server

I am trying to call a method of a COM server using InvokeMember.
The method has the following signature:

```
            void InsUpdOpInstance(
                        [in] long inIdOperDescr, 
                        [in] long inIsWait, 
                        [in] VARIANT stVariables, 
                        [in] long inIdProc, 
                        [in, out] VARIANT* inIdOperInst, 
                        [out] VARIANT* inReturnCode, 
                        [out] VARIANT* stErrorMessage);
```

My problem is getting back inIdOperInst parameter value.
The following code does not work:

```
var parameters = new object[] {12,0,"test",25655,DBNull.Value,null,null};
ParameterModifier modifier = new ParameterModifier(parameters.Length);
modifier[4] = true;
modifier[5] = true;
modifier[6] = true;

var ret = WFType.InvokeMember("InsUpdOpInstance",BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,null,Server,parameters,new ParameterModifier[]{modifier},null,null);
```

After the call parameters[4] does not change the value
Following code working fine:

```
dynamic serv = Server;

object inError = null;
object stError = null;
object inId = DBNull.Value;
serv.InsUpdOpInstance(12,0,"test",25655,ref inId,out inError,out stError);
```

After calling the parameter inId value was changed
Why InvokeMember doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Following code working fine:

```
var parameters = new object[] {12,0,"test",25655,new System.Runtime.InteropServices.VariantWrapper(DBNull.Value),null,null};
ParameterModifier modifier = new ParameterModifier(parameters.Length);
modifier[4] = true;
modifier[5] = true;
modifier[6] = true;

var ret = WFType.InvokeMember("InsUpdOpInstance",BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,null,Server,parameters,new ParameterModifier[]{modifier},null,null);
```

The fix is wrapping ref parameter to System.Runtime.InteropServices.VariantWrapper class